# Getting friends' information through Facebook Connect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, privacy

I have an app that needs to gain access to a user's friends' information.
For example, say I decided to connect to example.com with Facebook Connect.
Now example.com has the information about me (name, picture, education etc...). example.com requires to know something about my friend, John Smith, whom I can see the profile information of through facebook. Is there a way I can give example.com access to John Smith's details? (Even basic ones)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can query "/me/friends" to get names and ids of someone's friends.

Check out their [Graph OAUth API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api) for more details.

Comment: I was actually aware of this, but I should have clarified further in my question. I'm looking to get specific information about friends, like their education. Is that possible?

Comment: You can use the friends information (id and name) to get the publicly available information using the user API and the user ids:  https://graph.facebook.com/<user_id>.

Comment: But not other information about them (i.e. education)? thanks!

Comment: It depends on what information that user has made public.  Some people have education hidden, others don't.